# How to keep it CRUD and RESTFull in rails (concrete example)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, model-view-controller, routes, nested-routes

I've difficulties with keeping my controllers not too complicated and with the basic actions rails creates when we scaffold.

Could someone tell me if the approach below is the right one.

I've a model `Project` and those basic routes it:

```
GET   /projects            ->   Project#index
GET   /projects/new        ->   Project#new
POST  /projects            ->   Project#create
GET   /projects/:id        ->   Project#show
GET   /projects/:id/edit   ->   Project#edit
PATCH /projects/:id        ->   Project#update
PUT   /projects/:id        ->   Project#update
```

Now I would like to allow the user to accept the project. First he has a summary view where he can push a button and it should change some value in the model.

My first attempt was

```
GET   /projects/:id/accept ->   Project#accept
POST  /projects/:id/accept ->   Project#accept_update
```

This just doesn't feel right.

So I 'm wondering if I should do it in this way:

```
GET   /projects/:id/accept ->   Acceptations#new
POST  /projects/:id/accept ->   Acceptations#create
```

But then, I've my Acceptations  controller that is dealing with `Project` models. What starts being confusing for me.

On top of that, if I go with the second options, should the path be `/projects/:id/acceptations/new` this seems long and confusing for the end user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a convention (sometimes known as "heroku REST style") to put these "extra" methods as "actions" under the main resource.

So you'd have this for accepting the project.

```
 POST /projects/:id/actions/accept
```

What this route resolves to doesn't matter from the REST viewpoint. Could be an action in `ProjectsController`. I would likely create a dedicated controller just for this action, `controllers/projects/actions/accept_controller.rb`

As for the `new` route, you don't need it for json api. And in case of a GUI (such as your website), you maybe don't need a separate page as well. Instead, it'd just be a small form with "accept" button somewhere on project show page.

Comment: Makes sense. How would you reference this controller in your routes.rb? If I do `post "/projects/:id/actions/accept", to: 'Accept#create'` will rails be able to find it?

Comment: @DanielCosta: yep, should be able to find it.

Comment: Would it be a problem if we decide to have another model that needs acceptation like `/offers/:id/actions/accept` ?

Comment: @DanielCosta: no problem. Just make another route and another controller.